# Restrict public webapi only to my app and website

Tags: ios, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a .NET WebApi that will be accessed by IOS app and from a website with angular.
Some parts of the api data is public. That means we will not ask for user to login to view this data.

But we don't want others to use this api to access these data. These data has some commercial value and we are only publishing it free for our website and APP users.

We thought about an API KEY. But anyone might be able to access this key from client JavaScript or if they de-compile the app.

What might be a good solution to allow public users to access this data through only our site/app, but restrict other users from accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using authentication, like OAuth2. The user(s) will have to "log on" to use your app and/or website

Comment: hi alpinescrambler, Thanks for the suggestion, but the issue is business would like to show this data on our webpage and apps without login. But we don't like anyone else to access this api and show this data on their website.